# How to use callbacks right?

Tags: java, multithreading, callback

I mess with some patterns, to make code more modular. So I have something like this:

```
class A implements ICallback {
     MyObject o;
     B b = new B(this, someParameter);

     @Override
     public void callback(MyObject o){
           this.o = o;
     }
}

class B {
     ICallback ic;
     B(ICallback ic, someParameter){
         this.ic = ic;
     }

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
             // some calculation
             ic.callback(myObject)
         }
    }).start(); 
}

interface ICallback(){
    public void callback(MyObject o);
}
```

I have to wait for `MyObject` in `A`, so I'm using the `callback` to notify `A` if the work of the `Thread` in `B` is done. But now i have to put all the logic to handle `MyObject` and further processing in the `callback`.

Can I avoid that somehow or is that the right way?

Comment: Why would you need to avoid that? Is there any reason?

Comment: Not clear what you want to do and what to avoid. In principle, your code is acceptable, but remember, A.callback() is called from the thread in B, so if you want to access fields of A from other thread, e.g. the thread which created the instance of A, then you need to add some synchronization.

Comment: I asked to avoid that because my whole programm depends on MyObject. So all work has to be done in that callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is basically sound, but `class A` should probably not implement `ICallback` itself. The more typical, and more flexible, scheme is to pass an instance of an anonymous callback implementation into `B`.

Also note that all the processing of the callback will be done on the thread started by `B`.

Related to the above observation is the answer to your misgivings about `callback` doing all the processing of `MyObject`: there is fundamentally no other way to do it because the action of providing `MyObject` is initiated by `B`'s thread and the control can only flow from that method outwards. If you wanted the processing to jump over to the main thread, you would need a more complex scheme involving blocking queues.

Comment: Yeah what you mean is IoC. But my thoughts are about to check if the thread is done or more specific if MyObject is instantiated in class A and ready to be used outside the callback. I'm asking because the only thing which comes to my mind is polling.

Comment: Polling wouldn't be a brilliant choice, and neither would be blocking the thread in the anticipation of the event. Actually the best way is to do all the logic from the callback, and specifically that's how the most modern generation of asynchronous Java I/O APIs work.